# How do I concatenate cells and ignoring empty cells

Tags: excel, merge, calc

How can I merge 2 Columns contents in One another cells. I used Open Office Calc Software.

Cell A ; Cell B - but some of cell B Columns are empty Strings/contents.

I try like this

= CellA & " ; " & CellB.

It work ok, but i don't want to have the Seperate symbol ";" after end of CellA contents if the CellB is Empty.

Could someone point me in the right direction on how to achieve this in OpenOffice Calc.

Many thanks in advance.

best regards,
zoram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given two cells A1 and B1:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B1),A1,A1&";"&B1)
```

For more information, in Calc look at Insert -> Function List.

Comment: hi Lieslie, thanks. my columns are D and E. Some of E columns cell are empty. I used like you told me here =if(isblank(E1),D1,D1&";"&E1)  - but I got Err:508 in calc.

Comment: Thanks, Leslie, I got it now. =IF(ISBLANK(E1);D1;D1& ";" &E1)